# Composite Foreign Key from Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, key, composite-key

I am building the schema of one of my databases. I have two of the following tables...

```
CREATE TABLE User(
userID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE Tool(
toolID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY(toolID)
)
```

I want to create a table called hasTool that has two primary keys of both tables using a foreign key constraint. However, in addition to that, I want to make both of those fields, a composite key of the new table hasTool. I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to yield the expected behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE gcHasCoordinates (
userID INT NOT NULL,
toolID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userID , toolID ),
CONSTRAINT foreign_key_to_User FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Coordinate(coordinateID) ,
CONSTRAINT foreign_key_to_Tool FOREIGN KEY (toolID ) REFERENCES Tool(toolID)
);
```

I want to allow the table to allow multiple instances of userID or toolID, but not both, and be existing values on both Tables User and Tool.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should work correctly except that you are referencing the wrong table names `REFERENCES User (userID)` and `REFERENCES Tool (toolID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what is the problem ?

Except for

```
CONSTRAINT foreign_key_to_Tool FOREIGN KEY (toolID ) REFERENCES Tool(toolID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Where you are referencing to incorrect table GeoCache instead of Tool. It should be working I think.

Edit: Here have a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21717)

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo. I was editing it for this post, but the underlying query is consistent.

Comment: Oh! But you didn't answer what is wrong. I created table of my own in fiddle you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it only worked if I added the INDEX to both of the fields. I don't know why, but it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you shold use identical datatypes. `INT` and `INT NOT NULL` are different types